# Conversion error while using iterator with pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, dictionary, iterator

```
struct trie_node {
    char ch;
    std::unordered_map<char, trie_node*> children;
    trie_node() {
        ch = '\0';
    }
};
class Trie {
private:
    trie_node* trie_root;
public:
    Trie() {
        trie_root = new trie_node();
    }
    void insert_recursive(std::string str, trie_node* root, int len, int init) {
        if (len == 0) {
            return;
        }
        std::unordered_map<char, trie_node*>::iterator it;
        it = root->children.find(str[0]);
    }
};
```

I am trying use iterator but it gives me error when i assign `root->children.find(str[0]);`

> "no suitable conversion function from "std::_List_iterator>>>" to "std::_List_iterator>>> *" exists"

How do I solve this issue?

Comment: Your error message is incomplete and makes no sense. In any case just use automatic type deduction, to avoid iterator types mess: `auto it = blabla.find()`.

Comment: [Cannot reproduce](http://ideone.com/S3IYiD). Post an example that actually *fails*, include your include-list and a reproducing `main()`.

Comment: This is definitely not the code causing compiler-error. Post relevant code.

Comment: Title was changed to relate more to the actual problem